# Depletion regime in a MOS capacitor

Tags: mosfet, energy-band

I was watching a video lecture recorded by my Uni prof, where while dealing with the depletion regime in MOS Capacitors he defined the depletion regime as the regime where \$\psi_S < \phi_F\$, where \$\psi_S\$ is the surface potential wrt deep inside the body, and \$\phi_F\$ is equal to \$(E_{Fs} - E_i)/e\$. He also remarked that at \$\psi_S = \phi_F\$ the surface properties would resemble that of an intrinsic semiconductor, and asked us to think about it, hinting at the fact that \$\psi_S = \phi_F\$ would mean that the actual Fermi level and intrinsic fermi level coincide at the surface (**HOW**? I don't know, I guessed that in point 2 below)

I tried to think about it and failed to grasp it fully. I hope someone will be able to get this thing across me; meanwhile here are the points I managed to conclude:

1. When the fermi levels coincide, then the electron density at the surface becomes equal to the intrinsic carrier concentration, as $$n_{surface} = n_i\exp\bigg(\dfrac{E_F - E_i}{k_BT}\bigg)$$
2. We know, the total amount of band-bending is equal to the the electronic charge (e) \$\times\$ the potential of the oxide surface wrt the body \$\psi_S\$. Thus, if \$\psi_S = \phi_F\$ then the bands should meet at the oxide surface.

Comment: A search of [Fermi level](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fermi+level+) on the Physics stackexchange produces 500 results. Perhaps this question is better suited to the Physics stackexchange.

Comment: @ChesterGillon No response from Physics SE as well. I hope someone answers my question on this site